# Where do I store general config parameters in Silex?

Tags: php, configuration, silex

I have some general parameters I would like to share all along my application like path information ("baseurl"). Where would you ideally store this information in Silex?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After writing this question I came across the [`ConfigServiceProvider`](https://github.com/igorw/ConfigServiceProvider):

You can store your config data in json or yml files and access them through `$app["name.of.config.var"]`.

Replacements to add values dynamically to the config files on setup are also supported. The only thing I did not manage so far is to inject the baseurl via the `$app["request"]` api into the config files.

Comment: I recommend that you get the baseUrl from the request directly when you need it.

Comment: To https://github.com/igorw/ConfigServiceProvider I would recommend https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler

Answer (score 4):

I would store it in `Silex\Application`. It's a DI-container based on Pimple, so you can just do:

```
$app['baseUrl'] = '/';
```

Since `$app` pretty much gets passed around everywhere, you will also have access to this everywhere.

Comment: I have a config.php file which I include after the `Application` instance has been bootstrapped, it just sets config values on `$app`. This is the best solution.